# "with" keyword does not work with "cv2.VideoCapture(0)" in python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, computer-science

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

with cv2.VideoCapture(0) as cap:
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Title", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1):
            break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Throws error:
 "**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/openCV/Basic_Video/Basic.py", line 4, in 
    with cv2.VideoCapture(0) as cap:
AttributeError: __enter__**"

Answer (score 2):

The `with` keyword is not supported for `VideoCapture`. All examples that I found always declare it first:

[How to process images of a video, frame by frame in video streaming using Opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954889/how-to-process-images-of-a-video-frame-by-frame-in-video-streaming-using-opencv)

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

[cv2.videocapture.read() does not return a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989627/cv2-videocapture-read-does-not-return-a-numpy-array)