# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size' - how to face detection using mtcnn?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, face-detection, face-recognition

i'm trying to build face recognition in real time in neural network(facenet network) using pytorch and face detection using MTCNN 
i've tried this for detecting faces in real time  (from webcam) but doesnt work
read frames then going through mtcnn detector

```
import cv2  
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(True):      
   ret, frame = capture.read()     
   frames_tracked = []      
   print('\rTracking frame: {}'.format(i + 1), end='')     
   boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame)     
   frame_draw = frame.copy()     
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame_draw)     
   for box in boxes:
       draw.rectangle(box.tolist(), outline=(255, 0, 0), width=6)          
       frames_tracked.append(frame_draw.resize((640, 360), Image.BILINEAR))      
   d = display.display(frames_tracked[0], display_id=True)     
   i = 1     
   try:        
      while True:
          d.update(frames_tracked[i % len(frames_tracked)]) 
          i += 1     
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass  
   if cv2.waitKey('q') == 27:     
     break  

  capture.release() 
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it will rise this error :

this is the entire traceback http://dpaste.com/0HR58RQ

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

is there a solution for this problem ? what caused this error? thanks for your advice

Comment: I'm almost sure that you are not actually reading the image. trying seeing waht's happening with `retret` and `frame`, they might be empty

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: can you print `frame` at each iteration? i want to see the last value before this traceback.

Comment: it will work without (boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame) ) line , updated the post with entire traceback @steviestickman

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi print(frame) output : None ,

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990546/7284763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at that error again.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

so, somewhere in your code you(or mtcnn) are trying to call `size` attribute from a `None` variable. you are passing `frame` to `mtcnn` using following command :

```
 boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame)
```

this is exactly where you see that error. because you are passing a None variable to `mtcnn`. in order to prevent it, you can prevent it before calling this method. in other words :

```
ret, frame = capture.read()
if frame == None:
    continue
```

Comment: thanks fixed but one more error i got (RuntimeError: number of dims don't match in permute
)